# How to arrange collectionview cells closely according to text in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, cell

I have given collectionview constraints

```
 height = 50, leading = trailing = top = 10
```

i have taken label inside containerview in cell

cell containerview constraints

```
 bottom = top = 5, horizontal center
```

label constraints with containerview

```
 leading = trailing = top = bottom = 5
```

code in didload:

```
   let serviceLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    serviceLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    serviceLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    serviceLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
          self.servicesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = serviceLayout
```

**i am getting like this** i need one near by another

[image]

**i need like this**

[image]

how do i get collectionview cells near by one another, pls do help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your collection view in storyboard

- Go to size inspector
- Set scrollview indicator insets left and right as follows

[image]

Comment: given like that still not coming.. is there any other thing to change?

Comment: Try by adding         collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this custom Layout

```
class LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) ->     [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

guard let oldAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
    return super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
}

let spacing = CGFloat(6)

var newAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
var leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left
for attributes in oldAttributes {
    if attributes.representedElementCategory == .supplementaryView {
        newAttributes.append(attributes)
    } else {
        if (attributes.frame.origin.x == self.sectionInset.left) {
            leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left
        } else {
            var newLeftAlignedFrame = attributes.frame
            newLeftAlignedFrame.origin.x = leftMargin
            attributes.frame = newLeftAlignedFrame
        }
        leftMargin += attributes.frame.width + spacing
        newAttributes.append(attributes)
    }
}
return newAttributes
}
}
```